# Populate a Listbox from a database

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to fill my ListBox 'lstCategories' with the content of a database and all I see is nothing, here's the code :

```
public void FillCategories()
{
    SamsonEntities db = new SamsonEntities();

    var ListCats = (from cat in db.Categories
                    select new CategoryDisplay()
                    {
                        CategoryID = cat.CategoryID,
                        CategoyName = cat.CategoryName
                    }).ToList();

     //for (var i = 0; i < db.Categories.Count();i++ )
     //{
     //    lstCategories.Items.Add(....);
     //}
}
```

I don't know what to place into the line of my 'for', so I put it in comments

Comment: is it winforms? tag your question correctly

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the list as the ListBox datasource?

```
 lstCategories.DataSource = ListCats;
```

That should be enough.

As per your comment you need to set up the DisplayMember of your list to match the property to show:

```
lstCategories.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
```

And you probably want to setup the ValueMember too:

```
lstCategories.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
```

Comment: Yes and I see "SamsonLogiciel.CategoryDisplay" instead of the names of my categories

Comment: Override ToString in your CategoryDisplay class

Comment: How can I do this Saragis?

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain how to configure what your list box shows.

Comment: It's not working, I see the ID of my categories, but the numbers are the good ones

Comment: My teacher told me to fill it with a For but I don'T know what to place between the brackets. Is my For okay?

Comment: Almost. You must loop over ListCats otherwise you are accessing the db twice. And then add each element lstCategories.Items.Add(ListCats[i])

Comment: It's not even working, can we start a chat so you can see my code in real-time please?

Comment: I solved the problem, I just Override ToString my CategoryDisplay's CategoryName and it's working, suggested by Saragis :)